# MVC inline editing suggestions needed

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a html table loaded with data from server side and I want to do inline editing on click or double click on a cell on blur or enter event I want to send the data back to the server in order to keep the changes and on the final save I need to save it in database with the changes.

I have used Jquery Datatable and it seems I am struck on sending the value back to server side.

any other alternatives or suggestions?

I have used the sample which is in the below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165410/ASP-NET-MVC-Editable-DataTable-jQuery-DataTables-a

The server side function is not called at all from the client side

Comment: could you post the markup your using ?

Comment: Have you seen this? [https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple)

Comment: What exactly you stuck with? Logic you described is achievable with Datatables so why you need alternatives?

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph. How are you doing to save the value in the database if you don't sent the value to the server?

Comment: Please show your code so we can help you